# Unit test failing on EF Entry.State

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

Is it possible to unit test this?

```
public class MyRepository<T> where T : IdentityUser, new()
{
   public async Task UpdateAsync(T user)
    {
        _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.Entry(user).Property("UserName").IsModified = false;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

The [TestInitialize] adds 1 user to the repository

```
_user = new IdentityUser { Id = "70a038cdde40" };

IDbSet<IdentityUser> users = new FakeDbSet<IdentityUser> { _user };

var dbContext = new Mock<MyDbContext<IdentityUser>>();
dbContext.Setup(x => x.Users).Returns(() => users);

_repository = new MyRepository<IdentityUser>(dbContext.Object);
```

and I'm trying to test with this

```
private MyRepository<IdentityUser> _repository;

[TestMethod]
public async Task UpdateUser_Success2()
{
    var user = await _repository.FindByIdAsync("70a038cdde40");
    Assert.IsFalse(user.EmailConfirmed, "User.EmailConfirmed is True");

    user.EmailConfirmed = true;

    await _repository.UpdateAsync(user);

    (...)
}
```

But it dies on 1st line of UpdateAsync. Is the test that is wrong or the UpdateAsync implementation? Is there any way I can test it?

**Edit**

I added as suggested by Belogix

```
 dbContext.Setup(x => x.Entry(It.IsAny<IdentityUser>()))
                       .Returns(() => dbContext.Object.Entry(_user));
```

That gets me closer, I think, but still have the non-virtual error: Invalid setup on a non-virtual member: x => x.Entry(It.IsAny())

Comment: What is `_context` at the point you run your test? A mock of something or a real thing (pointing to a DB)? Have you stubbed the relevant parts so that calling it is all plumbed in?

Comment: @Belogix I've updated my question hope it answers yours

Comment: No, close but if you look at my answer you need to mock `Entry` to return `user` NOT `State` as that is property of your class... So use my example of mocking `Entry` and try again... That way you can set state etc on that mock object. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I did try that, but returning users[0] doesn't work because it can't apply indexing to type IDbSet<IdentityUser> and users.First doesn't work either because IdentityUser can't be converted to DbEntityEntry<IdentityuUser>

Comment: The type returned from Entry must be of type DbEntityEntry<IdentityUser>, _user is just IdentityUser, know what I mean? Sorry I think I deleted you comment by mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best quote ever: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection" - Butler Lampson.

It looks like this can't be tested directly without adding some additional abstraction. I had to refactor my UpdateAsync method this way

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(T user)
{
    SetEntityStateModified(user);
    SetPropertyIsModified(user);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public virtual void SetPropertyIsModified(T user)
{
    _context.Entry(user).Property("UserName").IsModified = false;
}

public virtual void SetEntityStateModified(T user)
{
    _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

And then update my test code in the Initialize

```
_repository = new Mock<MyRepository<IdentityUser>>(dbContext.Object);
_repository.Setup(x => x.SetEntityStateModified(It.IsAny<IdentityUser>()));
_repository.Setup(x => x.SetPropertyIsModified(It.IsAny<IdentityUser>()));
```

My test then finally passes

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task can_update_user_details()
{
    //Arrange
    var user = await _repository.Object.FindByIdAsync("70a038cdde40");
    Assert.IsFalse(user.EmailConfirmed, "User.EmailConfirmed is True");

    //Act            
    user.EmailConfirmed = true;

    await _repository.Object.UpdateAsync(user);
    var newUser = await _repository.Object.FindByIdAsync("70a038cdde40");

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(newUser.EmailConfirmed, "User.EmailConfirmed is False");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ChangeTracker in dbContext tracks changes and hold the entities that are changed. So you can assert the changed entity is among them.

```
Assert.IsTrue(dbContext.Object.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(entry =>
            entry.State == EntityState.Modified &&
            entry.Entity is IdentityUser &&
            (entry.Entity as IdentityUser).Id == users[0].Id // Here you can check if it is actually the same user
        ));
```

For the property it would be something like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(_context.Object.ChangeTracker.Entries().Any(entry =>
            entry.Property("UserName").IsModified == false &&
            entry.Entity is IdentityUser &&
            (entry.Entity as IdentityUser).Id == users[0].Id // Here you can check if it is actually the same user
        ));
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have not stubbed your `context` correctly... I am not at a computer with Visual Studio so here is some pseudo code that should demonstrate what I mean. Replace the `IsAnything` with either your mocking frameworks way of ignoring argument or actually the user if you want to handle different responses.

```
// Existing context initialisation...
var dbContext = new Mock<MyDbContext<IdentityUser>>();
dbContext.Setup(x => x.Users).Returns(() => users);

// NEW: Mock what / how Entry is going to return when called (i.e. return a user)
dbContext.Setup(x => x.Entry(IsAnything)).Returns(() => users[0]);
```

Comment: This will not work since Entry is not virtual in EntityFramework, therefore not mockable